# Sticky Menu On Homepage but on the other pages doesn't appear (wordpress)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, header, sticky

I have a website (donaotilia.zdk.pt) and i did a mask that overlaps and image on header and when scroll's down the mask disappears and become a sticky menu, it does that in home page but on the other pages the sticky menu doesn't follow the scroll down . How can i fix this ? Help please.

Thanks

Comment: Can you send us the link of your website ? It feels like there is a javascript error on all pages except the homepage that break the script. Or maybe something, but mooooore informations please !

Comment: The link is "http://donaotilia.zdk.pt/" , i would like the same effect of the header on "homepage" to be in all pages.

Comment: Anyone can help? :S